# (CLOSED) PHP Textarea replace returns key (new line) with br tags than save it to txt file

Tags: php, file, save, textarea

i've asked something similar here, but i cannot find any solution.
As i've already told, i'ma  beginner with PHP, and what i'm trying to do is:

I have a form, with date, title and text.

- title is a text input field, works perfectly.
- text is a text area input field, doesn't work.

What the user writes in the input fields, will be saved into a text file like this:

```
2013-01-01|title|text
```

I choose this cause after saving the results, i want to explode into arrays.
The problem is:

-When i write down something into the textare field, and i press enter to create a ne line, the output text file is like this:

```
2013-01-01|title|text
text2
text3
text4
```

instead of:

```
2013-01-01|title|text<br>text2<br>text3<br>text4
```

i can i obtain this result? and if i obtain this result, when i splt all into arrays using this code

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $array = file("news/news.txt");
     foreach($array as $row){
            $data = $titolo = $testo = "";// initialize the valiables 
            $split = explode('|', $row);
            $data = (isset($split[0])?$split[0]:"");
            $titolo = (isset($split[1])?$split[1]:"");
            $testo = (isset($split[2])?$split[2]:"");
            $i++;
            print '<div id="'.$i.'" class="news"><div class="date">'.$data.'</div><div class="title">'.$titolo.'</div><div class="text">'.$testo.'</div></div>';
            } 
?>
```

will i be able to obtain into the output html file something like this:

```
<div id="1" class="news">
   <div class="date">2013-01-01</div>
   <div class="title">Title1</div>
   <div class="text">text 1<br>
                     text 2<br>
                     text 3<br>
   </div>
</div>
```

my other answer is this, that explain the problem into another point of view.

[How to save textarea content inside a .txt file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920231/how-to-save-textarea-content-inside-a-txt-file-with-php)

thanks a lot for now.

**UPDATE**

After using nl2br inside my code, the text output obtained is this:

```
05-01-2014|asd|asd<br />
asd<br />
asd<br />
asd<br />
```

**UPDATE**

I've solved using

`str_replace( "\n", '<br />')`

instead of nl2br

thanks to you all for your replay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are expecting `2013-01-01|title|text<br>text2<br>text3<br>text4` in text file.

Then you should convert the textarea content using `nl2br` before storing into file.

```
$content = nl2br($_POST["content"]);
```

Comment: with you code i obtain this output file:
05-01-2014|asd|asd<br />
asd<br />
asd<br />
asd<br />
the new line is still there, how to remove the new line too?

Comment: where you are getting new line? Can you update your question with latest attempt? Because we can't see the proper output in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the nl2br function already? https://www.php.net/nl2br